# Error while sending a request to fluxpoint api

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, request

it's me again... *Sorry for asking so many times a day, but I'm really an idiot.*

So basically I'm trying to send a request to the fluxpoint api by using this code:

```
async welcome(username, avatarurl, background, membercount, icon, backgroundname, filename){
        let req = {}
        req.username = username;
        req.avatar = avatarurl;
        if (background == null) {req.background = "#aaaaaa"} else {req.background = background}
        if (membercount) req.members = "Member #"+membercount
        if (icon) req.icon = icon
        if (backgroundname) req.banner = backgroundname
        console.log(req)
        let usedClient = axios.create({
            baseURL: apiUrls[0],
            timeout: 5000,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': this.token,
                'Content-Length': 0,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            data: JSON.parse(req),
            responseType: 'arraybuffer'
        })
        console.log(usedClient)
        console.log(apiUrls[0]+api1endpoints[1])
        let res = await usedClient.get(api1endpoints[1])
        return res
    }
```

Here is the code I'm using for testing it:

```
const fluxpoint = require('./index')
const Client = new fluxpoint.Client("my fluxpoint token")

async function tt(){
    let t = await Client.welcome("Koro~ (Baka)#7963", "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/304541381798658048/36806f6ae648b9ebc8303443b0be101c.png", "#FFFFFF", 1, "neko", "space")
    console.log(t)
}
tt()
```

And, here is the error the fluxpoint api sends me:

`Failed to parse json, The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Excepted the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.`

I tried everything, but JSON.parse(my data) sends me `Unexcepted token o in JSON at position 1`

I'm being desesperate and I hope somebody can help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are parsing the raw json.It throws an error

JSON.parse takes string as parameter.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

And from official doc you cannot use data in get request.

https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config

```
 // `data` is the data to be sent as the request body
  // Only applicable for request methods 'PUT', 'POST', and 'PATCH'
  // When no `transformRequest` is set, must be of one of the following types:
  // - string, plain object, ArrayBuffer, ArrayBufferView, URLSearchParams
  // - Browser only: FormData, File, Blob
  // - Node only: Stream, Buffer
  data: {
    firstName: 'Fred'
  }
```

So try passing the data

```
let res = await usedClient.get(api1endpoints[1],{
  params: {
    data: res
  }
})
```

I've tested the endpoint it works only if responseType is 'text' or  'stream'

Comment: Even if I do like that, the api answers me "{
  "status": "error",
  "success": false,
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Failed to parse json, The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is
true. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."
}"...

Comment: Hey can you add output of console.log(res) to the question?

Comment: Yup I'm going to do that

Comment: is api on node js environment??

Comment: I'm making a wrapper that sends the request to the api. I don't know if it runs on nodejs. You can check the [documentation](https://docs.fluxpoint.dev/main/api) if needed.

Comment: In case my answer helped you, please upvote it and mark it as correct. Ive put some time in this post.

Comment: Ive tested it bro. I even generated token from the fluxpoint api. Now what error you are getting?

Comment: can you add me on Discord? It will prevent spamming here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210052/discussion-between-supercool-and-koro-baka).